# Is engine start failure reason for dealership mechanics to check fluid levels?

Tags: toyota, gasket, cylinder-head

My daughter's car was towed to the nearest Toyota dealer because it stalled. All lights came on in dash and it smelled burned. We were given a clean bill of health the next day just to have it towed back again since it died on her again on her way home. This time they said the radiator was empty and the head cylinder warped. We weren't charged the first time but the second bill was $4700 for our 10 year old mechanically sound and well maintained RAV 4. Really???

Comment: This looks to be more of a comment on an incident you had.  Do you have a question?  You can hit the edit button below your question to add characters to your post and put the question you have out there.  Remember, we answer technical questions here and not subjective ones.  Welcome to the site!  Cheers.